# Removing items in array in React using context and reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been building an application that pulls data from a database onto a React frontend in the form of items in an array. Each item then has information on it with a button to visit the URL on that item plus a button to delete the item from the database. This functionality works, I have made API's that interact with the database and everything is great. When the delete button is pressed, the event gets removed from the database but it doesn't remove the item from the UI. Could someone please show me where I could be going wrong?

I've created a component for the events, with logic to map all items to a grid on the front end:

```
const Events = () => {
    const eventContext = useContext(EventContext);

    const { events, loading } = eventContext;

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner />;
    } else {
        return (
            <div style={userStyle}>
                {events.map(event => (
                    <EventItem key={event._id} event={event} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

const userStyle = {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(3, 1fr)",
    gridGap: "1rem"
};

export default Events;
```

I've then created an EventItem component to show data from each item in the array:

```
const EventItem = ({ event }) => {
    const eventContext = useContext(EventContext);

    const { deleteEvent } = eventContext;

    const { _id, Client, Keyword, Source, Url, URL, Shodan_URL, Title, Date, Ip, PhishingAgainst, Preview, Verdict, Port, Product, Version, Expires } = event;

    const onDelete = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        deleteEvent(_id);
    }

    return (
        <div className="card bg-light text-center">
            {Client ? <h3>Client: {Client}</h3> : null}
            {Keyword ? <p>Keyword: {Keyword}</p> : null}
            {Source ? <h4>Source: {Source}</h4> : null}
            <hr></hr>
            {Url ? <p>URL: {Url}</p> : null}
            {URL ? <p>URL: {URL}</p> : null}
            {Shodan_URL ? <p>URL: {Shodan_URL}</p> : null}
            {Title ? <p>Title: {Title}</p> : null}
            {Date ? <p>Date: {Date}</p> : null}
            {Ip ? <p>IP: {Ip}</p> : null}
            {PhishingAgainst ? <p>Phishing Target: {PhishingAgainst}</p> : null}
            {Preview ? <p>Preview: {Preview}</p> : null}
            {Verdict ? <p>Verdict: {Verdict}</p> : null}
            {Port ? <p>Port: {Port}</p> : null}
            {Product ? <p>Product: {Product}</p> : null}
            {Version ? <p>Version: {Version}</p> : null}
            {Expires ? <p>Expires: {Expires}</p> : null}
            <div>
                <a type="button" href={Url || URL || Shodan_URL} className="btn btn-dark btn-sm my-1">Go to Source</a>
                <button onClick={onDelete} className="btn btn-danger btn-sm my-1">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Here is the file with my state:

```
const EventState = props => {
    const initialState = {
        events: [],
        loading: false,
    }

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(EventReducer, initialState);

    // Get Events
    const getEvents = async () => {
        setLoading();
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/events");
        dispatch({
            type: GET_EVENTS,
            payload: res.data
        })
    };
    // Clear events
    const clearEvents = () => {
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_EVENTS });
    };

    // Delete Event
    const deleteEvent = async id => {

        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/events/${id}`);
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_EVENT,
            payload: id
        })

    };
    const setLoading = () => {
        dispatch({ type: SET_LOADING });
    }

    return <EventContext.Provider
        value={{
            events: state.events,
            loading: state.loading,
            getEvents,
            clearEvents,
            deleteEvent,
        }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </EventContext.Provider>
}

export default EventState;
```

Here is where the state passes the deletion of the event to the reducer:

```
import {
    GET_EVENTS,
    CLEAR_EVENTS,
    DELETE_EVENT,
    SET_LOADING
} from '../types';

export default (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_EVENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: action.payload,
                loading: false,
            };
        case SET_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        case CLEAR_EVENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: [],
                loading: false
            };
        case DELETE_EVENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                events: state.events.filter(event => event._id !== action.payload)
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The item is removed from the database, but not from the front end. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks for responding, do I have to include addiitonal logic in the deleteEvent function? Any suggestions on what exactly i can add?

Comment: I thought that **events: state.events.filter(event => event._id !== action.payload)** would solve this by updating the state without having to re-fetch data from the DB?